# MySql - Create sum from main and second table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySql:

1. **main:**

**and_fakture
field:id, organizatorId,...**

2. **second:
   and_stavke
   field:id,idFakture,ukupno,...
   where and_fakture.id=and_stavke.idFakture**

**ukupno** is **numeric**

How can i **sum(ukupno) from organizatorId** ?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but you want something like this?:

```
SELECT organizatorId, SUM(ukupno) 
FROM and_fakture
INNER JOIN and_stavke ON and_fakture.id = and_stavke.idFakture
GROUP BY organizatorId
```

This will give you the sum of ukupno by every organizatorId